# TypeScript pattern match against a string or Blob (type union = string | Blob)

Tags: typescript, types

I've defined a union type,

```
type TextData = string
type BinaryData = Blob
type DataType = TextData | BinaryData
```

Which I would like to use in a function

```
function doSomethingWithData(data: DataType): void {
    if (data instanceof TextData)
      // doesn't work (type being used as a value error)

    if (typeof data === 'Blob')
      // doesn't work (typeof data === 'object')

    if (data instanceof Blob)
      // works, but I don't want to use a type alias
}
```

Is there anyway of getting this to work or do I need to rethink the design?

Comment: I know why it doesn't work, the type alias is compiled away after compilation. But is there another approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know why it doesn't work, the type alias is compiled away after compilation. But is there another approach?

You must use runtime available variables for runtime checks.

## Expose to runtime

You can export `BinaryData` as a runtime variable

```
type TextData = string
type BinaryData = Blob
const BinaryData = Blob;
type DataType = TextData | BinaryData

function doSomethingWithData(data: DataType): void {
    if (data instanceof BinaryData) {
      // works
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't expect a response from the TypeScript guy himself. Thank you.